# how do i rewrite url to remove ?id=13

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hello can anyone help me out being trying to remove some part of my url
eg:

From this

```
http://localhost:8888/www.mysite.com/admin/account_expenses?return=account1
```

To this

```
http://localhost:8888/www.mysite.com/admin/account_expenses?
```

And I would like it still be able to `$_GET['return']` value to echo error. and also how to apply to my other like that.

Thank you.

Comment: from whereever you're calling the first url, change method to "POST" and use `$_REQUEST['return']` or `$_POST['return']` to access it.

Answer (score 2):

One quick question is where is the URL coming from, is it from a `form` or from a `link`. 
If it is from a form, then your form attribute `method="GET"` should be `method="POST"`.
If it is from a link then you will use `htaccess` to format the `URL` as @vishnu stated.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)&return=[0-9a-z]+&(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

add this code to folders .htaccess file 
then you will able to get the variable value using $_GET without present paramenters in URL

Comment: hello i tired the .htaccess code, i can still see the variable in the url.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^?]*)\? 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/admin/account_expenses? [R,L]
```

Try this instead for redirection to your page
`http://www.example.com/admin/account_expenses?`